# Url веб - приложений

Tags: url, хеширование

Часто замечаю в веб-приложениях такой Url `example.com/yr121MGZ2lB`
Допустим, создавая что-либо в приложении и сохраняя он создает уникальный url для моей сцены.

Пожалуйста, можете объяснить мне принцип его работы?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Принцип работы чего? Генерации идентификатора, способ получения данных по нему, или что-то еще?

Comment: Принцип хранения и получения данных, к примеру где хранится это yr121MGZ2lB в базе данных? И при обращении он отправляет мне json строку. как это реализовано?

Comment: Опубликовал ответ, но вопрос _"И при обращении он отправляет мне json строку. как это реализовано?"_ слишком общий. Вы можете посмотреть популярные фреймворки (некоторые я перечислил в ответе), а потом задать вопрос, ориентируясь на конкретную задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Где хранится это yr121MGZ2lB в базе данных?

Это зависит от того, как она спроектирована. Это может быть обычный столбец символьного типа с ограниченной длинной, это может быть [UUID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-uuid.html) тип. Идентификатор может быть сгенерирован одним из стандартных хэширующих алгоритмов, а может быть результатом самописной хэш-функции, призванной уменьшить коллизии. Он может генерироваться абсолютно случайно, а может зависеть от входных данных. Способов реализации - громадное количество, и выбирать один из них нужно отталкиваясь от ограничений задачи.

> И при обращении он отправляет мне json строку. как это реализовано?

Аналогично, способов реализации сервера, отдающего json на запрос огромное количество для каждого языка. Тут Вам и *Spring* для *Java*, и *Django* для *Python*, и *Ruby on Rails* для *Ruby*, и *<Ваш любимый фреймворк>* для *<Ваш любимый язык>*.

Comment: Спасибо! Один маленький вопрос в базе данных mysql, нормально ли хранить помимо id еще сгенерированный hash, или объединить их т.е стобец id и внем hash.

Comment: Это зависит от целей и объемов Вашей системы. Если Вы планируете делать распределенную систему, то при использовании целого числа в качестве PK, Вы рискуете столкнуться с коллизиями на разных инстансах БД. В этом случае Вам могут быть полезны GUID вместо ID: [здесь](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) расписаны их плюсы и минусы. С другой стороны, можно для каждой БД вогнать ID в определенные рамки, и тогда тоже не будет проблем. Если у Вас не планируется высоконагруженная система, то хранить hash рядом с id я считаю приемлимым.